# Wordpress looping through posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I wonder if someone can explain the following, I am following a tutorial on wordpress, I see this code being used to loop through the post and display them, however I'm slightly confused as to whats actually happening here.

```
<?php 
if( have_posts() ):
    while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    <?php endwhile;     
endif;
?>
```

The paricular section that concerns me is `while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>`

So firstly, the syntax here is not something I have seen before, you have the while loop brackets open and close then after that you have `: the post()` what is this second part? I though that the condition for the while loop needs to be inside the `while()`. What is this `: the_post()` what does it do?

also, the method `have_posts()` returns true if there are posts, I don't understand why this isn't an infinite loop, since surely `have_posts()` will always be true as long as there is at least one post in the database.

lastly, I like to use PHP short tags, now when I do, this code no longer works, here is my version of this code with short tags, can someone show me where I am going wrong.

```
<? if ( have_posts() ): ?>
    <? while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(): ?>
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    <? endwhile; ?>
<? endif; ?>
```

PHP storm is highlighting the last `:` in `<? while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(): ?> as the error, but if I change it to a`;` i get the following error

`Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\laragon\www\blog\wp-includes\post-template.php on line 293`

I realise there are a couple of questions here, I apologise, I just want to fully understand whats actually happening here, not just blindly copy and paste. Hope you understand.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) While Loop Syntax**

The syntax that's being used is an alternative way of doing "control structures" in PHP, as documented here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Essentially, it's an alternative way of writing the following:

```
while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    ?>
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    <?php
}
```

There's no difference to how the code functions, it's just that it's sometimes easier to match up than using curly braces

**2. `have_posts()` and `the_post()`**

You're right in that this will return true if there are posts, but it's the call to the `the_post()` function that's stopping it from infinitely looping.
What `the_post()` will do is set all of the variables necessary to access the post data (such as the `$post` global variable), then it will increase a counter by 1.
What this means, if you've only got one post, is that the second call to `have_posts` will now return false, as the counter is equal to the number of posts it has available.

**3. PHP Short Tags**

I'm guessing this is because you're server isn't set up to use short tags. You'll need to enable `short_open_tag` settings within your php.ini config.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: Thanks mate, this was spot on.